# "pip install somepackage" freezes powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I've been using python in both my office pc and my personal laptop and on both machines typing in powershell:

```
pip install somepackage
```

works normally.

Strangely enough, when I attempt to do it on my personal desktop, powershell remains on halt infinitely.

I found a solution for this by doing:

```
python -m pip install somepackage
```

The above is fine, and I can live with typing an extra 8 characters whenever I want to install a new package but I'm curious to understand what is happening.

Thanks :)

PS: I have added *C:/Python27/Scripts* to *Path* in the system variables already and it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`pip.exe` is located in `C:\Python27\Scripts`. You need to add that folder to your `PATH` environment variable. If you added it to the system environment you need to start a new PowerShell console to make the change become effective.

If you want the path to become available in the current console you need to add it to the `PATH` variable in the current console as well (the console gets a copy of the environment when it starts, it doesn't pick up changes to the system or user environment at runtime):

```
$env:Path += ';C:\Python27\Scripts'
pip install somepackage
```

However, `C:\Python27\Scripts` not being included in the `PATH` should only result in an error message that PowerShell doesn't recognize the command. It shouldn't freeze the console. Perhaps there's some other cmdlet/command/function/alias named `pip` that gets executed instead. Try running `Get-Command pip` to verify that.